# Probability of drawing numbers based on past drawing counts?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics

Just a mathematical thought I had, and I couldnt find a relevant answer.

Lets assume that 3 numbers are drawn from the following list: `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10`. The drawing is without replacement (if we draw `1`, we have `2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10` left, and so on). Now, if we know that there were 10 previous drawings with the following statistics:

1. `2, 4, 7`
2. `1, 4, 8`
3. `3, 8, 10`
4. `1, 5, 6`
5. `2, 7, 10`
6. `5, 7, 9`
7. `6, 7, 10`
8. `1, 4, 7`
9. `4, 8, 9`
10. `8, 9, 10`

So now we know that the following numbers were drown x times as follows:

- `1` = 3 times total
- `2` = 2 times total
- `3` = 1 times total
- `4` = 4 times total
- `5` = 2 times total
- `6` = 2 times total
- `7` = 5 times total
- `8` = 4 times total
- `9` = 3 times total
- `10` = 4 times total

How can one calculate the probability of drawing, `X, Y, Z` on the 11th drawing?

Is this probability purely based on the `count` of previous number drawings? Or also on the number combinations of each individual drawings?

Comment: It depends on who is handing us the numbers and what they want. In other words which distribution is being drawn from? Do we know we will be getting numbers from the same random distribution each time or can it be altered? Who decides?

Comment: For the sake of assumption, it is done by the same person, computer, or system. The random distribution will stay the same, and we cannot change it.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have nearly enough data to estimate dependencies.

The best you can do is estimate weighted probabilities.   Such as:

$$\Pr(\{1, 7,10\}) \simeq \dfrac{3}{30}\dfrac{5}{27}\dfrac{4}{22}+\dfrac{3}{30}\dfrac{4}{27}\dfrac{5}{23}+\dfrac{4}{30}\dfrac{3}{26}\dfrac{5}{23}+\dfrac{4}{30}\dfrac{5}{26}\dfrac{3}{21}+\dfrac{5}{30}\dfrac{3}{25}\dfrac{4}{22}+\dfrac{5}{30}\dfrac{4}{25}\dfrac{3}{21}$$

Comment: which additional information is needed? What if there were 100 previous drawings instead of 10?

Comment: @KingsInnerSoul Well, there are $120$ distinct combinations that can be selected, and you'd want enough draws to get a reasonable estimate of the probability of each.